# How to fetch price through another table where $product->name is equal to $order->product

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have 2 table product and order and in order i want to get price through product table
This is my form

```
<div id="TextBoxDiv1">
     <input type="hidden" value="{{Auth::user()->name}}" name="order_by">
     <input class="text email" type="text" name="quantity[]" placeholder="Quantity" required="" id='textbox1' style="width: 230px; height: 41px; margin-top: 10px">
     <div class="form-group row">
     {{-- <label class="col-md-3 mt-3">Single Select</label> --}}
     <div class="col-md-9">
     <select class="select2 form-select shadow-none" style="width: 230px; height: 41px; margin-top: 10px" name="product[]">
             <option>Select Product</option>
             @foreach ($products as $product)
                   <option value="{{ $product->name }}">{{ $product->name }}</option>
              @endforeach
      </select>
    </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

This is my OrderController and i not understand how to get price as the value that we get from form is in array and i want to convert it to string and through that name i want price through products table

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $products = Product::all();
    $request->validate([
        'order_by' => 'required',
        'product' => 'required',
        'quantity' => 'required',
        'status' => 'sometimes',
        'price' => 'sometimes',
    ]);

    $order = new Order();
    $order->product = implode(',', $request->product);
    $order->quantity = implode(',', $request->quantity);
    // $order->price = ;
    $order->order_by = $request->order_by;
    $order->status = $request->status;
    $order->save();
    return redirect()->route('user/pending', compact('products'))->withSuccess('Done');
}
```

this is the image of orders table
[image]

and this is pic of products table
[image]

Comment: provide your order and product model code.

Comment: @Vega OP didn't get answer on this question but he got an answer on other question so I voted to close this...but ultimately OP get the solution of his problem so now It doesn't matter...Sure I will transfer my vote **:)**

Answer (score 0):

set the value of option as $product->id and then get the price in controller

In Blade:

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
   <option value="{{ $product->id }}">{{ $product->name }}</option>
@endforeach
```

In Controller:

```
$product = Product::find(implode(',', $request->product));

$order->product = $product->name;
$order->price =$product->price;
```