# How to fetch price through another table where $product->name is equal to $order->product in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have 2 tables: product and order. In order, I want to get the price through the product table.

**Form**

```
<div id="TextBoxDiv1">
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ Auth::user()->name }}" name="order_by">
    <input class="text email" type="text" name="quantity[]"
           placeholder="Quantity" required="" id="textbox1"
           style="width: 230px; height: 41px; margin-top: 10px">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <select class="select2 form-select shadow-none"
                    style="width: 230px; height: 41px; margin-top: 10px"
                    name="product[]">
                <option>Select Product</option>
                @foreach ($products as $product)
                    <option value="{{ $product->name }}">{{ $product->name }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is my OrderController. I do not understand how to get the price as the value that we get from the form is in an array, and I want to convert it to a string, and through that name, I want the price through the products table.

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $products = Product::all();
    $request->validate([
        'order_by' => 'required',
        'product' => 'required',
        'quantity' => 'required',
        'status' => 'sometimes',
        'price' => 'sometimes',
    ]);

    $order = new Order();
    $order->product = implode(',', $request->product);
    $order->quantity = implode(',', $request->quantity);
    // $order->price = ;
    $order->order_by = $request->order_by;
    $order->status = $request->status;
    $order->save();
    
    return redirect()->route('user/pending', 
        compact('products'))->withSuccess('Done');
}
```

**Orders table**
[image]

**Products table**
[image]

**Order model**

```
use HasFactory;

protected $table = 'orders';

protected $fillable = [
    'order_by',
    'product',
    'quantity',
];
```

**Product model**

```
use HasFactory;

protected $table = 'products';

protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'brand',
    'price',
    'detail',
    'image',
];
```

Comment: self-duplicate [How to fetch price through another table where $product->name is equal to $order->product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67149807/how-to-fetch-price-through-another-table-where-product-name-is-equal-to-order)

Comment: Please don't repost your questions. Instead, improve them to be answerable. Your edit will bump the question at the front and it will be again visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store product_id as foreign key in order table and make relationship between order and product. And you do not have to store product price and name in order table.

**Order Model**

```
use HasFactory;

protected $table = 'orders';

protected $fillable = [
    'order_by',
    'product',
    'quantity',
];

public function product()  
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Product', 'product_id'); 
}
```

And you have to get product name and price like this

```
{{$order->product->name}}
{{$order->product->price}}
```